# Can I give a C# parameter a default value?

Tags: c#

In C# can we do the following like C++?

```
public void myMethod(int i, MyClass obj, int value=100){

}
```

Another question is MyClass is a reference type, if there is no `ref` before it, it will pass a copy of the MyClass into the method but not the reference?

thanks,

Comment: Have you tried testing it to see if it compiles with a default value?

Comment: Passing a class always passes a reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Others have correctly answered the optional parameter part: you can specify a default value for a parameter in C# 4. (There are various restrictions, e.g. mandatory parameters have to come before optional ones, and the default value has to be a compile-time constant.)

`<gratuitous plug>`[See C# in Depth, 2nd edition](http://manning.com/skeet2), chapter 13 for more details`</gratuitous plug>`

For the "parameter passing" aspect - all arguments are passed by value by default, but in the case of reference type the argument is a reference, not the object. Changes to the *object* will be visible to the caller, but if you change the *parameter* itself to refer to a different object, that change *won't* be visible to the caller. (It won't change the value of the caller's variable.) See my [article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for details.

Comment: when the C# 4 will be available?

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA: The release candidate of VS2010 is out now for MSDN subscribers and later today for others. The actual release is likely to be in April I believe.

Answer (score 10):

Not in C# up to C# 3 (which is the current version). In C# 4 you can have [optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739%28VS.100%29.aspx) with default values.

Regarding the question about MyClass and `ref`, parameters are passed by value. For reference types, you could say that the "value" of a variable (or argument) is the reference to the instance, so if you modify properties on the `MyClass` instance, you modify the same instance as the caller has a reference to.

Jon Skeet has written a good article on the subject: "[Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)"

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to accomplish basically this exact behavior in C# 3 and earlier is to overload the method in question:

```
public void myMethod(int i, MyClass obj, int value=100){
    // do whatever
}

public void myMethod(int i, MyClass obj) {
    myMethod(i, obj, 100);
}
```

And if `MyClass` is a reference type, then `obj` will be a reference to a `MyClass` object. adding the `ref` keyword would make `obj` a reference (still) **passed by reference**. In other words you could do:

```
obj = new MyClass();
```

...and you'd be modifying the reference that was passed to `myMethod`. Otherwise (without `ref`) you'd only be modifying the local reference; and the *original* reference, whatever was passed to `myMethod`, would stay unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in C# 4.0 for optional parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can, but only in c# 4.0. see http://elegantcode.com/2010/01/28/c-4-0-optional-parameters-exploration/